# Using async-await not returning the values

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, promise, async-await

I use the following code which works! I was able to fetch the data in the spread (then) , http200

```
Promise.all([
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
      data: qs.stringify({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
      }, {
        'scope': 'run:crud'
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    }),
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
      data: qs.stringify({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
      }, {
        'scope': 'exe:crud'
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    })
  ]).then(axios.spread((...responses: AxiosResponse[]) => {
      const aToken = responses[0];
      const bToken = responses[1];
    }).catch(function(error: any) {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
    });
```

Now I want to wrap it with **async function** which return two response (responses[0], responses[1] )

I’ve created this function

```
const FetchData = async (): Promise<{ run: string; app: string }> => {

let aToken:string;
let bToken:string;
Promise.all([
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
      data: qs.stringify({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
      }, {
        'scope': 'run:crud'
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    }),
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
      data: qs.stringify({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
      }, {
        'scope': 'exe:crud'
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    })
  ]).then(axios.spread((...responses: AxiosResponse[]) => {
      aToken = responses[0];
      bToken = responses[1];
    }).catch(function(error: any) {
      console.log("Error: " + error);
    });

// add this return 
return {
    run: aToken ,
    app: bToken
};

)}
```

Now I’ve created function to call it and get the tokens

```
async function main() {

    let val = await FetchData();
    console.log(val)


}
```

The problem is that I got empty value in the `val` property, while put a breakpoint inside main function 
I see that I got into the console, before I actually get the values from the `).then(axios.spread((` ,
Any idea how to adopt the code to return the value from the spread operator and then call to the console?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14220321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `async-await` correctly. You need to await `Promise.all`. Once both promises are resolved, response data will be in a property named `data` inside each response object that you get from `axios`. If you need whole response object then you can destructure it

Here's an example

```
const FetchData = async (): Promise<{ run: string; app: string }> => {
    try {
        const [response1, response2] = await Promise.all([
            axios({
               ...
            }),
            axios({
               ...
            })
        ]);

        return {
          run: response1,
          app: response2
        };

   } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
   }
};
```

Here's a [demo](https://repl.it/repls/UniqueFelinePriority) that fetches data from 2 endpoints of [jsonplaceholder api](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/)

Comment: Thanks, i will try it now. what regard the `then` , I dont see it ?

Comment: inside the the `then` Im getting the data, could you add it to the example ?

Comment: you don't need `then` block when using `async-await`. see the demo of jsonplaceholder api that i included in my answer. It fetches data from 2 endpoints

Answer (score 1):

```
const res = await Promist.all([...])
return { run: res[0], app: res[1] }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the position of your return statement:

Updated code with changes:

```
const FetchData = (): Promise<{ run: string; app: string }> => {

let aToken:string;
let bToken:string;
// Return the promise here

return Promise.all([
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
      data: qs.stringify({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
      }, {
        'scope': 'run:crud'
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    }),
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://oauth2.-arch.mand.com/oauth2/token',
      data: qs.stringify({
        'grant_type': 'client_credentials'
      }, {
        'scope': 'exe:crud'
      }),
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic NTgwNjgtMDhhZTczOGNl',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      }
    })
  ]).then(axios.spread((...responses: AxiosResponse[]) => {
      aToken = responses[0];
      bToken = responses[1];

      // This return is for getting the data once the promise is resolved either with then or await
      return {
         run: aToken ,
         app: bToken
      };
    }).catch(function(error: any) {
       console.log("Error: " + error);
       return error;
    });

)}
```

As you are returning the value before the promise is resolved so you are not getting any data.
You need to return promise and inside then you need to return the required data, to get once the promise is resolved in invoking function.